# Phase 10 - Who goes first?

Tags: phase-10

I've played Phase 10, the card game, for years, but recently I started playing the android app version. It has always been my understanding that the dealer role rotates to the left after each hand, but, in the app, I can't figure out how they're decided who goes first each round. I've played one-on-one games, and the same player will go first 3 or more times in a row. Anyone have an idea on this?

Answer (score 1):

In most rules given for the game it is stated that one player is chosen to be the dealer ([source 1](http://www.tactic.net/site/rules/FIN/03140.pdf), [source 2](http://howdoyouplayit.com/phase-10-card-game-rules/), [source 3](http://www.natlassoc.org/fun/games/phase10/phase10r.htm).) 

There is no mention of the dealer role going to another player in those.

Wikipedia says:
`One player is chosen to be the dealer (alternately, the deal can rotate to the left after each hand).`([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_10))
This seems to indicate that having the deal rotate is an alternate rule or houserule rather than an official rule.